# Array com PHP e PostgreSQL

Tags: php, array, postgresql

Olá, estou com um problema no retorno de informações do banco de dados. Ele está me retornando um array desordenado e com informações de outro usuário do banco.

**Aqui esta a Index:**

```
<?php
  SESSION_START();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "pt-br">
  <head>
    <!-- MetaTags para aceitar caracteres especiais, ajustar compatibilidade com navegadores e dispositivos móveis -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Título -->
    <title>Test</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font-Awesome CSS -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';?>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    <script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Este é o meu código PHP:**

```
include_once('connect.php');
    $msg_ok=false;
    $msg_error='Sistema fora do ar.';
    if(isset($_POST['telefone'], $_POST['nome'])):
        if($_POST['telefone']!=""):
            if($_POST['nome']!=""):
            $telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
            $nome=$_POST['nome'];
            $consulta=pg_query($connect, ("SELECT nome, cpf FROM mailing WHERE telefone='$telefone'"));
            if(pg_num_rows($consulta)>0):
                $msg_ok=true;
                $tel=pg_fetch_array($consulta);
                session_start();
                $msg_error="Logado corretamente.";
            else:
                $msg_error="Usuário ou nome incorretos.";
            endif;
        else:
            $msg_error="nome incorreta.";
        endif;
    else:
        $msg_error="Usuário não existe.";
    endif;
else:
    $msg_error="Todos os dados requiridos.";
endif;
$saidaJson=array('resposta' => $msg_ok, 'msg' => $msg_error);
echo json_encode($saidaJson);
```

Eu apenas quero que o usuário entre no sistema pelo seu número de celular(invés de um login e senha), então o PHP irá me retornar um array com o nome, idade, etc...

Estou com uma dificuldade para realizar este retorno, mas estou pesquisando, não tenho muita experiência com PHP e nem com PostgreSQL, então fico meio perdido.

Comment: Deixa eu entender. Você quer que retorne um array com os dados a partir de um login? Se você deseja fazer um esquema de autenticação, deveria retornar apenas 1 resultado existindo ou não. Agora a questão de retorno de dados desordenados, não consegui compreender muito bem. Talvez esse seu **telefone** esteja retornando mais de um usuário, pois no seu banco esteja cadastrado mais de uma vez o mesmo telefone.

Comment: Eu consegui arrumar o erro, abaixo do "session_start();" eu não declarei nada, minha sessão estava vazia e os logs que meu navegador estava exibindo eram de uma sessão que eu havia aberto antes de modificar o meu código PHP. Para resolver esse erro eu apenas declarei variáveis para armazenar os valores de retorno do PostgreSQL: $_SESSION['nome']=$tel[0];